# Datatable, how to limit values that are input directly on it, is there a “changevalue” event?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a dataset which contains the following tables:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZisY.png

As you can see it's possible to edit it's values directly (and i prefer it that way), but sometimes i wanna limit its value, for example, if the user attempts to place a number 3, i want the program to display a message:

MessageBox.Show("This parameter can only use values between 0 and 1.";);
and then proceed to set the value to 1 (which is closest to 3)

is this possible? What is the action that makes the program recognize the value the user has just input?

edit: it's pretty simple, you can use something like this

```
if (Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Columnname"].Value) > 5)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("The value can't be above 5.");      
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Columnname"].Value = "5";
}
```

where `[0]` is the row number (starts at zero), basically the `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Columnname"].Value` command allows you to control directly a row, and a column value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataTable` itself is in-memory representation of the data.
Whereas `DataSet` contains collection of DataTables.

Looking at the image provided it seems your DataTable is bind with [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control.

Yes. You can track cell value changes by looking into following events of `DataGridView`:

1. [DatataGridView.CellValueChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. [DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you i solved it with your help. I have a question though, how do you know if the datatables are binded with datagridview? does it mean i can't re-define values programaticly?

Comment: I am glad it helped you. Well the image clearly shows datagridview control.  That is how I knew

Comment: You can always make changes in datatable. Re-define values, add or remove columns and rows.   After these change you could re-assign the datatable to the data source of datagridview control.